# Prob. 14, Sec. 1.5 in Erwine Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $C([0,1])$ be the set of all continuous real-valued function on $[0,1]$, let $d(f,g)=\int_0^1 |f(t) - g(t)|dx$.

We note that the exercise 14 needs exercise 13, which gives us a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of the form
$$
f_n(t)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             n &   if  & 0 \leq t\leq n^{-2}, \\
             \\ t^{-1/2} &   if  & n^{-2} \leq t\leq 1.
             \end{array}
   \right.$$
which is a Cauchy sequence on $C([0,1])$. Show  that this Cauchy sequence does not converge.

**Here we are using the following ideas:**

Suppose that this sequence is convergent, i.e, there exists $f\in C([0,1])$ such that $f_n$ converges to $f$. Then, we have
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_0^\alpha |f_n(t)-f(t)|dt =0\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_\alpha^1 |f_n(t)-f(t)|dt =0$$
for all $0<\alpha<1$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}<\alpha$.

But let us observe that $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_0^\alpha |f_n(t)-\infty|dt$$ does not exists and $$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_\alpha^1 |f_n(t)-t^{-1/2}|dt =0.$$

Therefore, there not exists $f\in C[0,1]$ such that the sequence $f_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f_k(t)=t^{-1/2}$ for $t\ge n^{-2}.$ If $f_n$ tended to $f$ we would  have $f(t)=t^{-1/2}$ for $t\ge n^{-2}.$ As $n$ was arbitrary we would get $f(t)=t^{-1/2}$ for $t>0.$ The function $f$ is unbounded, hence it cannot be extended to a continuous function on $[0,1].$

Answer (score 0):

*(note that you are asking no question, so I'm just guessing what you want here)*

As written, the argument makes no sense. You don't say what $\alpha$ is, and you seem to assume that the continuous function $f$ assumes the non-existent value $\infty$ on $[0,\alpha]$.

Instead, what you need to notice is that $f_n\to f$, where $f(t)=t^{-1/2}$, that limits in a metric space are unique, and that no continuous function on $[0,1]$ can agree with $f$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$\int_0^1\left|\frac1{\sqrt t}-f_n(t)\right|\,\mathrm dt=\int_0^{\frac1{n^2}}\left(\frac1{\sqrt t}-n\right)\,\mathrm dt=\frac1n,$$
if there was a function $f\in C[0,1]$ such that $d(f_n,f)\to0,$ we would have
$$\int_0^1\left|\frac1{\sqrt t}-f(t)\right|\,\mathrm dt\le\frac1n+d(f_n,f)\to0$$
hence
$$\forall\alpha\in(0,1]\quad\int_\alpha^1\left|\frac1{\sqrt t}-f(t)\right|\,\mathrm dt\le\int_0^1\left|\frac1{\sqrt t}-f(t)\right|\,\mathrm dt=0$$
i.e.
$$\forall\alpha\in(0,1]\quad\forall t\in[\alpha,1]\quad f(t)=\frac1{\sqrt t},$$
i.e.
$$\forall t\in(0,1]\quad f(t)=\frac1{\sqrt t}.$$
But there is no such function $f\in C[0,1].$